# hackerrank 'Grep' -A problemsolve

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I got some confusing results while solving question 'Grep' - A in hackerrank
here is the link:
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/unix-text-processing-2017/challenges/text-processing-in-linux-the-grep-command-4/

```
grep -i -w -e 'the' -e 'that' -e 'then' -e 'those'
```

is the right answer for the question.

My first attempt was

```
grep -i -E 'the|that|then|those'
```

but is wrong in the second testcase, what is the difference between them? And why is my first code wrong?

Comment: Did you ask on that site?  There may be specific rules regarding correct answers.

Comment: Don't expect readers to goto remote sites to view your problem description. You should cut/paste exact code and error messages into your Q and use the {} tool from the menu at the top left of the edit box to format your code/data/errors so they are easily searchable and readable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: That page 404s for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `-w` flag is the difference, and it's an important one. Without this flag set, "theme" will match the pattern "the", with the flag set it won't, because the flag means to match full words.

If you add `-w` to the second command, then it should become equivalent to the first.

It's important to pay attention to such details. Every single character can be important, and every command line argument can certainly be very important. In this example, you could easily find the explanation in `man grep`.

Btw, another equivalent solution without using the `-w` flag:

```
grep -i -E '\<(the|that|then|those)\>'
```

This has th same effect, because the `\<` means "start of word",
and "end of word",
effectively matching one of the complete words within the `(...)` separated by `|`.